# Convert JSON to list of SObject in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I would like to know if it is possible de deserialize a JSON to list of SObject in javascript?

This is my JSON :

```
{label: 'Id', fieldName: 'id', type: 'Number'},{label: 'Agency', fieldName: 'agency', type: 'Text'},{label: 'Csat', fieldName: 'csat', type: 'Number'},{label: 'Date', fieldName: 'date', type: 'Date'},{label: 'Amount', fieldName: 'amount', type: 'Decimal'},{label: 'Recontact', fieldName: 'recontact', type: 'Boolean'},{label: 'Logo', fieldName: 'logo', type: 'Text'}
```

I guess it is not possible currently with the method JSON.parse().
At the end, I need to get something like this :

```
 [
            {label: 'Opportunity name', fieldName: 'opportunityName', type: 'text'},
            {label: 'Confidence', fieldName: 'confidence', type: 'percent'},
            {label: 'Amount', fieldName: 'amount', type: 'currency', typeAttributes: { currencyCode: 'EUR'}},
            {label: 'Contact Email', fieldName: 'contact', type: 'email'},
            {label: 'Contact Phone', fieldName: 'phone', type: 'phone'}
        ]
```

If it is necessary, I can modify my JSON.

Can you help me please?
Aurélien

Comment: It would be easier to change your JSON to be sent/provided as an array.  I'm not sure if your JSON is an object of objects (there are not keys) or already an array (no braces to indicate this).

Comment: Your "JSON" is not valid JSON. You cannot have objects separated by comma at the top level.

Comment: I resolved my error.
First, I create the SObject list then I serialize my list to have it in JSON and it works.